# How can I lock the screen in Mac OS X 10.6?

Tags: macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Equivalent of Win-L on Mac](https://superuser.com/questions/19974/equivalent-of-win-l-on-mac)

What's the Mac equivalent of Windows' <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> command for locking the screen?

Comment: This has been partially answered in these 2 questions: http://superuser.com/questions/78222/applescript-to-lock-the-screen and http://superuser.com/questions/22155/lock-mac-after-n-mins-of-inactivity. Basically, there is no such key command equivalent.

Comment: Duplicate of "Equivalent of Win-L on Mac" at http://superuser.com/questions/19974/equivalent-of-win-l-on-mac (It's quite easy using the new "Service" Automator workflow in Snow Leopard.)

Answer (score 3):

http://osxdaily.com/2007/04/23/ask-os-x-daily-how-do-i-lock-a-mac-os-x-workstation/

Okay, one solution:
(1) System Preferences -> Desktop & Screen Saver:  set up a sleep corner for your screen saver
(2) System Preferences -> Security:  enable immediate password protection for your screen saver

Why step #2 isn't referenced from step #1 is beyond me.

Comment: 10.6 has better means than this. See the duplicate.